# Do poly-time algorithms exist whose time complexity is unprovable?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time

If not, is there a decision procedure that successfully classifies any 
polynomial time algorithm as poly-time within a time polynomially bounded 
by the length of the input algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean provably unprovable, or just unknown? Your follow-up question does not make sense, anyway; decidability of this question is unrelated to provability, and [the answer is "no" either way](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no).

Comment: seems to be research level question eg john sidles asked similar question on [cstheory.se]: [Does P contain languages whose existence is independent of PA or ZFC? (TCS community wiki)](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11691/does-p-contain-languages-whose-existence-is-independent-of-pa-or-zfc-tcs-commu)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example. Suppose that you're working within axiom system A, say ZFC. Gödel showed that if A is consistent then A can't prove that A is consistent. Consider the following program:

> On input $x$, go over all strings of length $\log |x|$, and check if one of them is a proof of the consistency of A. If so, loop for $2^{|x|}$ iterations. Otherwise, halt.

This is polynomial time if and only if A is consistent. If A could prove that this algorithm terminates in polynomial time then A has just proved that A is consistent, which is impossible if A is indeed consistent. Yet if we believe that A is consistent, then the machine *does* run polynomial time; but A unfortunately isn't strong enough to prove it.

Your second question asks whether there is an algorithm that, given a Turing machine $T$, answers in polynomial time whether $T$ is a polynomial time Turing machine. Unfortunately, this is undecidable. Suppose that we only consider Turing machines which don't depend on their input (say the first thing they do is erase their input). Such a machine $T$ runs is polynomial time if and only if it halts on the empty tape. Deciding whether a Turing machine halts is impossible.